# Zabbix & SNMPTT.log file access denied

Tags: fedora, selinux, zabbix

I'm having a problem with a file accesed by ZAbbix to proccess all the SNMP trap data using a file `/var/log/snmptt/snmptt.log`.

ZAbbix_proxy.log

```
 23323:20140430:105246.532 sleeping for 5 seconds
 23329:20140430:105247.070 cannot open [/var/log/snmptt/snmptt.log]: [13] Permission denied
 23329:20140430:105247.070 sleeping for 1 seconds
 23329:20140430:105248.070 cannot open [/var/log/snmptt/snmptt.log]: [13] Permission denied
 23329:20140430:105248.071 sleeping for 1 seconds
 23329:20140430:105249.071 cannot open [/var/log/snmptt/snmptt.log]: [13] Permission denied
 23329:20140430:105249.071 sleeping for 1 seconds
```

SE Linux Audit log.

```
time->Wed Apr 30 09:58:11 2014
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1398869891.560:41198): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=no exit=-13 a0=16ffee0 a1=0 a2=1 a3=8 items=0 ppid=23309 pid=23329 auid=4294967295 uid=995 gid=996 euid=995 suid=995 fsuid=995 egid=996 sgid=996 fsgid=996 ses=4294967295 tty=(none) comm="zabbix_proxy" exe="/usr/sbin/zabbix_proxy_sqlite3" subj=system_u:system_r:zabbix_t:s0 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1398869891.560:41198): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=23329 comm="zabbix_proxy" name="snmptt.log" dev="dm-5" ino=133641 scontext=system_u:system_r:zabbix_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:var_log_t:s0 tclass=file
----
time->Wed Apr 30 09:58:12 2014
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1398869892.560:41199): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=no exit=-13 a0=16ffee0 a1=0 a2=1 a3=8 items=0 ppid=23309 pid=23329 auid=4294967295 uid=995 gid=996 euid=995 suid=995 fsuid=995 egid=996 sgid=996 fsgid=996 ses=4294967295 tty=(none) comm="zabbix_proxy" exe="/usr/sbin/zabbix_proxy_sqlite3" subj=system_u:system_r:zabbix_t:s0 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1398869892.560:41199): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=23329 comm="zabbix_proxy" name="snmptt.log" dev="dm-5" ino=133641 scontext=system_u:system_r:zabbix_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:var_log_t:s0 tclass=file
```

I don't understand SELinux.

Anyone knows what flag i need to activate on file to avoid this file access denied messages from `SELinux` ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no such "flag". The closest would be a `boolean`, and according the [`zabbix_selinux(8)`](http://linuxmanpages.net/manpages/fedora19/man8/zabbix_selinux.8.html) manpage, there's no `boolean` defined to grant read access to a log file in an arbitrary location.

You don't give details regarding the actual labeling of the files under the `/var/log/snmptt/` directory. The expected labeling may or may not match the expected label of other SNMP related log files, as per `semanage()`:

```
# semanage fcontext -l | grep '/var/log/snmp'
/var/log/snmpd\.log.*           regular file       system_u:object_r:snmpd_log_t:s0
```

The solution, then, would be to grant `zabbix` read access to those logfiles. Filter you audit log using `audit2allow(1)`:

```
# echo "
> time->Wed Apr 30 09:58:11 2014
> type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1398869891.560:41198): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=no exit=-13 a0=16ffee0 a1=0 a2=1 a3=8 items=0 ppid=23309 pid=23329 auid=4294967295 uid=995 gid=996 euid=995 suid=995 fsuid=995 egid=996 sgid=996 fsgid=996 ses=4294967295 tty=(none) comm="zabbix_proxy" exe="/usr/sbin/zabbix_proxy_sqlite3" subj=system_u:system_r:zabbix_t:s0 key=(null)
> type=AVC msg=audit(1398869891.560:41198): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=23329 comm="zabbix_proxy" name="snmptt.log" dev="dm-5" ino=133641 scontext=system_u:system_r:zabbix_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:var_log_t:s0 tclass=file
> ----
> time->Wed Apr 30 09:58:12 2014
> type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1398869892.560:41199): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=no exit=-13 a0=16ffee0 a1=0 a2=1 a3=8 items=0 ppid=23309 pid=23329 auid=4294967295 uid=995 gid=996 euid=995 suid=995 fsuid=995 egid=996 sgid=996 fsgid=996 ses=4294967295 tty=(none) comm="zabbix_proxy" exe="/usr/sbin/zabbix_proxy_sqlite3" subj=system_u:system_r:zabbix_t:s0 key=(null)
> type=AVC msg=audit(1398869892.560:41199): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=23329 comm="zabbix_proxy" name="snmptt.log" dev="dm-5" ino=133641 scontext=system_u:system_r:zabbix_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:var_log_t:s0 tclass=file
> " | audit2allow


#============= zabbix_t ==============
allow zabbix_t var_log_t:file read;
```

The procedure to build a custom module is detailed in the `audit2allow(1)` manpage.

You'd normally build a module, install or update it, and test the behavior of your application under the new security restrictions, and further refine the module. This is easily done putting your machine in `permissive` mode while you test/develop a new module. Use `setenforce(8)` to do that.